# A second select tag which depends on the first ones' value

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to change the select tag a user selects based on the previous select tag option.So the second drop down menu (select tag) will depend on the previous one.

- First drop down menu: vehicle make
- Second drop down menu: vehicle model

Python flask code

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    make = request.form['make']
    model= request.form['model']
    print(model)
    print(make)

    return redirect('/')
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">

<select name="make">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="model">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

</html>
```

Comment: please describe the problem that you have, not only what you want to achieve in general

Comment: I'm not sure how to link the two at all

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: You're going to need to use javascript for this. Adding javascript tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jquery to change the second dom dynamically. Maybe like following:

```
var make = $('select[name="make"]').val()
$('select[name="model"]').html('<option value="' + make + '">' + make + '</option>')
```

Comment: I have no experience with jquery, do i just put it into the html?

Comment: just put it in the bottom of your html file. The structure can be:
`
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var make = $('select[name="make"]').val()
$('select[name="model"]').html('<option value="' + make + '">' + make + '</option>')
</script>
</html>
`

Comment: hi, I do that and get a blank html

Comment: Your origin code should be put between <body> </body> fields.
<html><body>
<form action="/signup" method="post">
<select name="make">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="model">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
</body>
<script> var make = $('select[name="make"]').val() $('select[name="model"]').html('<option value="' + make + '">' + make + '</option>') </script> 
</html>

Comment: oh i see :) how would i now add the options of car makes and manufacturers? e.g. if someone selects BMW it shows all the BMW models

Comment: The you should write some js code. For example, send an ajax request to be background to get data. Then, change the dom in the same way. Hope you got it.